# Invoking "cmake" failed

Tags: ros-kinetic, cv-bridge

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have previously installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and ROS kinetic on PC.
I try to  practice tutorial according this (http://wiki.ros.org/cv_bridge/Tutorials/ConvertingBetweenROSImagesAndOpenCVImagesPython)

I create a package using `catkin_create_pkg sample_opencv_pkg sensor_msgs opencv2 cv_bridge rospy std_msgs`.
the terminal shows

```
Created file sample_opencv_pkg/CMakeLists.txt
Created file sample_opencv_pkg/package.xml
Created folder sample_opencv_pkg/src
Successfully created files in /home/my/catkin_ws/src/sample_opencv_pkg. Please adjust the values in package.xml.
```

Then  I change direction to catkin_ws ,and use `catkin_make` .The terminal show the following error:

```
Base path: /home/my/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/my/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/my/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/my/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/my/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/my/catkin_ws/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/my/catkin_ws/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/my/catkin_ws/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/my/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/my/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/my/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/my/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/my/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gmock sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gmock will be built
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gmock': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.11
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 9 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - turtlebot3 (metapackage)
-- ~~  - turtlebot3_msgs
-- ~~  - turtlebot3_navigation
-- ~~  - sample_opencv_pkg
-- ~~  - turtlebot3_bringup
-- ~~  - turtlebot3_example
-- ~~  - turtlebot3_slam
-- ~~  - turtlebot3_teleop
-- ~~  - turtlebot3_description
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin metapackage: 'turtlebot3'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(turtlebot3/turtlebot3)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'turtlebot3_msgs'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(turtlebot3_msgs)
-- Using these message generators: gencpp;geneus;genlisp;gennodejs;genpy
-- turtlebot3_msgs: 3 messages, 0 services
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'turtlebot3_navigation'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(turtlebot3/turtlebot3_navigation)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'sample_opencv_pkg'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(sample_opencv_pkg)
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "opencv2" with any
  of the following names:

    opencv2Config.cmake
    opencv2-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "opencv2" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "opencv2_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "opencv2" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  sample_opencv_pkg/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'opencv2'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "opencv2" with any
  of the following names:

    opencv2Config.cmake
    opencv2-config.cmake
"opencv2" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  sample_opencv_pkg/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/my/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/my/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed

  Add the installation prefix of "opencv2" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "opencv2_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "opencv2" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  sample_opencv_pkg/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/my/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/my/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

here is the `Cmakelist.txt`:

```
        cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
    project(sample_opencv_pkg)
    
    ## Compile as C++11, supported in ROS Kinetic and newer
    # add_compile_options(-std=c++11)
    
    ## Find catkin macros and libraries
    ## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
    ## is used, also find other catkin packages
    find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
      cv_bridge
      opencv2
      rospy
      sensor_msgs
      std_msgs
    )
    
    ## System dependencies are found with CMake's conventions
    # find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS system)
    
    
    ## Uncomment this if the package has a setup.py. This macro ensures
    ## modules and global scripts declared therein get installed
    ## See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/user_guide/setup_dot_py.html
    # catkin_python_setup()
    
    ################################################
    ## Declare ROS messages, services and actions ##
    ################################################
    
    ## To declare and build messages, services or actions from within this
    ## package, follow these steps:
    ## * Let MSG_DEP_SET be the set of packages whose message types you use in
    ##   your messages/services/actions (e.g. std_msgs, actionlib_msgs, ...).
    ## * In the file package.xml:
    ##   * add a build_depend tag for "message_generation"
    ##   * add a build_depend and a exec_depend tag for each package in MSG_DEP_SET
    ##   * If MSG_DEP_SET isn't empty the following dependency has been pulled in
    ##     but can be declared for certainty nonetheless:
    ##     * add a exec_depend tag for "message_runtime"
    ## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
    ##   * add "message_generation" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
    ##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
    ##   * add "message_runtime" and every package in MSG_DEP_SET to
    ##     catkin_package(CATKIN_DEPENDS ...)
    ##   * uncomment the add_*_files sections below as needed
    ##     and list every .msg/.srv/.action file to be processed
    ##   * uncomment the generate_messages entry below
    ##   * add every package in MSG_DEP_SET to generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES ...)
    
    ## Generate messages in the 'msg' folder
    # add_message_files(
    #   FILES
    #   Message1.msg
    #   Message2.msg
    # )
    
    ## Generate services in the 'srv' folder
    # add_service_files(
    #   FILES
    #   Service1.srv
    #   Service2.srv
    # )
    
    ## Generate actions in the 'action' folder
    # add_action_files(
    #   FILES
    #   Action1.action
    #   Action2.action
    # )
    
    ## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
    # generate_messages(
    #   DEPENDENCIES
    #   sensor_msgs#   std_msgs
    # )
    
    ################################################
    ## Declare ROS dynamic reconfigure parameters ##
    ################################################
    
    ## To declare and build dynamic reconfigure parameters within this
    ## package, follow these steps:
    ## * In the file package.xml:
    ##   * add a build_depend and a exec_depend tag for "dynamic_reconfigure"
    ## * In this file (CMakeLists.txt):
    ##   * add "dynamic_reconfigure" to
    ##     find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS ...)
    ##   * uncomment the "generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options" section below
    ##     and list every .cfg file to be processed
    
    ## Generate dynamic reconfigure parameters in the 'cfg' folder
    # generate_dynamic_reconfigure_options(
    #   cfg/DynReconf1.cfg
    #   cfg/DynReconf2.cfg
    # )
    
    ###################################
    ## catkin specific configuration ##
    ###################################
    ## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package

## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if your package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES sample_opencv_pkg
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge opencv2 rospy sensor_msgs std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ library
# add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
#   src/${PROJECT_NAME}/sample_opencv_pkg.cpp
# )

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Declare a C++ executable
## With catkin_make all packages are built within a single CMake context
## The recommended prefix ensures that target names across packages don't collide
# add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node src/sample_opencv_pkg_node.cpp)

## Rename C++ executable without prefix
## The above recommended prefix causes long target names, the following renames the
## target back to the shorter version for ease of user use
## e.g. "rosrun someones_pkg node" instead of "rosrun someones_pkg someones_pkg_node"
# set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}_node PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME node PREFIX "")

## Add cmake target dependencies of the executable
## same as for the library above
# add_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME}_node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

## Specify libraries to link a library or executable target against
# target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
# )

#############
## Install ##
#############

# all install targets should use catkin DESTINATION variables
# See http://ros.org/doc/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/variables.html

## Mark executable scripts (Python etc.) for installation
## in contrast to setup.py, you can choose the destination
# install(PROGRAMS
#   scripts/my_python_script
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark executables and/or libraries for installation
# install(TARGETS ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_node
#   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
#   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
# )

## Mark cpp header files for installation
# install(DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}/
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_INCLUDE_DESTINATION}
#   FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h"
#   PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE
# )

## Mark other files for installation (e.g. launch and bag files, etc.)
# install(FILES
#   # myfile1
#   # myfile2
#   DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
# )

#############
## Testing ##
#############

## Add gtest based cpp test target and link libraries
# catkin_add_gtest(${PROJECT_NAME}-test test/test_sample_opencv_pkg.cpp)
# if(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME}-test)
#   target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}-test ${PROJECT_NAME})
# endif()

## Add folders to be run by python nosetests
# catkin_add_nosetests(test)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300363/invoking-%22cmake%22-failed/) by [Tommy Hay](https://answers.ros.org/users/36494/tommy-hay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

CMake can not find your opencv2 installation. As is a required component of the find_package command, compilation fails to success. Review your opencv2 install. It is not an ROS issue but machine configuration problem. Most common problems with CMake are that specific CMake Library Modules are missing so CMake can not recognize them (which I guess it is not your case, a classic example is Eigen).

Try also to check rosdep external dependencies that are not installed and soem of your package requires:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y
```

---

Originally posted by [Bogdar_](https://answers.ros.org/users/25988/bogdar_/) with karma: 136 on 2018-08-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0